# Resetting my Mac

Tags: macos, time-machine, high-sierra

Apparently I have issues with my partitions so someone on here suggested that I could reset my macOS.

If I do a time machine backup before resetting, does the backup inherit all partition issues or is it merely just saving files and their paths?

Do I need to look out for something else that might make my life harder?

Comment: What kind of problems are you having? People don't often have issues with partitions, unless they have been messing around with disk utility software?

Comment: @l008com Bootcamp is always having problems. Someone in another thread suggested that having a clean reset will fix all Bootcamp + APFS issues.

Comment: What kind of problems? Are you sure it's not normal Windows problems? Other than creating your bootcamp partition with the bootcamp assistant, have you messed around with the partition scheme at all? Are they telling you to repartition and then restore all of your data, or are they telling you to erase your data and start with a clean drive? Either way, this doesn't seem to add up.

Comment: @l008com: Usually, answers to the questions you are asking can be found by looking at the previous questions posted by the OP.

Comment: Please be more specific about what state your system is in. The usability of a TM backups may differ depending on the system state

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Time Machine saves a copy of your entire macOS partition, so it is not a good choice if your partition is already messed up. If it’s already messed up, you should backup your important files only by copying them to an external drive.

Time Machine doesn’t copy the partitioning table or other partitions. After you make the backup, boot into Recovery Mode by pressing <kbd>Command</kbd> and <kbd>R</kbd> at the same time during boot. After that, erase your whole drive using `diskutil eraseDisk` and restore your backup from Recovery Mode.

Comment: If one can boot to the partition which one wishes to save with Time Machine, then how should be backup be made? In other words, if a partition is already messed up, would there be any point to making a time machine backup?

Comment: Yea that's what I'm trying to get a confirmation about

Comment: @DavidAnderson Edited to provide more information.